# Google geocode API results - storing the data

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

This is a question specifically for the Google Developer Relations team.  I have read the Geocode API T&Cs and I am aware that I am not allowed to store data except by way of a temporary cache (e.g. for performance).  Is this the end of the matter?  I am developing a product which requires a search with results sorted by distance from a place, meaning that all my records need a lat/long.  I was intending to use the Geocode API to get the lat/long when a user adds a record, and then adding that lat/long info to the record.  We would then use the Haversine formula to calculate the relative distances and sort the results.

If I follow this approach, will I be in breach of the T&Cs?  If so, is there another approach using the Geocode API which will allow me to hold onto lat/long data so that I can sort my results by distance, within the letter of the T&Cs?

For anyone else commenting, please observe the following restrictions: (1) we don't have a budget to buy a postcode-lat/long dataset; (2) we don't want to use a static dataset of our own, eg GeoNames, because we don't want to have to maintain data which is, effectively, public; (3) we have to support users who have javascript disabled.

To be absolutely clear, what I need here is to have the lat/long for all of my records in hand so that I can do effective searching and sorting by distance relative to another lat/long as provided, e.g. by a user searching.

Google Team, please respond to this message with contact details so we can speak.

Comment: When the user adds a record give him a interface(map) where he can click on to locate the address and store this latLng.

Comment: Two issues here: (1) we have to support users without js enabled [see edit]; (2) does this not amount to the same thing - we are using a Google API (in your case, the Maps API) to get data and then keeping it in our DB, apparently in breach of Usage policy.

Comment: 2. There are free map-solutions you can use(e.g. openlayers or leaflet)

Comment: 2r. It's the lat/long data I need, primarily, not the ability to show a map.  According to their site, "Leaflet itself does not provide geocoding services...". I have also seen commentary that says the OpenLayers does not provide geocoding either.

Comment: 1. geonames(or other free ressources) may also be accessed via webservice, no need to download a complete dataset

Comment: I didn't say that leaflet provides a geocoding service...it provides a map where someone can click on to get (and store) the latLng(without restrictions)